# Social Networking Features using Django

Tags: django

We are planning to develop something similar to LinkedIn using Python and Django. As all of you must be aware that LinkedIn has a feature where it suggests "Users You May Know". It includes a lot of hierarchy suggestions like connect to first level of connections you may know, second level of connections you may know and so on. I wanted to know if there is a django plugin which I can use to maintain such hierarchies of users or is it something that has to be developed from the scratch. Has anyone ever developed something like this or is there some plugin or third part django app which I can use for this or something that supports Social Networking Features.

Apart from this, I also wanted to know if Django is feasible and scalable to develop something like LinkedIn/Facebook and which can support upto 3 Million users ?

Please let me know your thoughts ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like [Django-FOAF](http://code.google.com/p/django-foaf/) will do what you want.  It's a little unclear as to the scope of what you're trying to achieve, but it appears that this will at least let you traverse a social graph.

As to the second part of your question, almost nothing is going to scale to 3 million users without some care and attention to detail.  I'd humbly suggest that learning a lot about web scalability would be a nice idea.  A blanket answer like "yes" or "no" here  is going to be meaningless without reference to your userbase's usage patterns, hardware, and specific application.

Comment: Also found something that is really useful. This is an integrated collection of Django applications that provides the most commonly needed social networking features, including openID support, email verification etc ... Pinax [link](http://pinaxproject.com/)